# Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file

Tags: solidity, etherscan, nodejs, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

MY hardhat.config.js

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");
const Goerli_RPC_URL = process.env.RINKEBY_RPC_URL;
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const ETHERSCAN_API = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API;
console.log(Goerli_RPC_URL);
console.log(PRIVATE_KEY);
console.log(ETHERSCAN_API );
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.9",
  networks:{
    Goerli:{
      url:Goerli_RPC_URL,
      chainId:420,
      accounts:[PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
    etherscan:{
      apiKey:ETHERSCAN_API,
    }
  },
};
```

error in the terminal .....

```
Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

  * Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.Goerli.url - Expected a value of type string.   
  * Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.etherscan.url - Expected a value of type string.  
To learn more about Hardhat's configuration, please go to https://hardhat.org/config/

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH8 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces
```

**I was correctly getting my privatekey && etherscan url in console but my Goerli url was been shown as undefined and even when i typed npx hardhat i was getting this above err**

MY deploy.js

```
const ethers = require("hardhat");
async function main()
{
  const contractfactory = await new ethers.contractFactory("Lock");
  console.log("deploying contract");
  const contract = await contractfactory.deploy(5);
  await contract.deployed();
  console.log(`the contract is deployed to : ${contract.address}`);
}
main().then(
  ()=> process.exit(0)
).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
  process.exit(1);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your config

```
etherscan:{
      apiKey:ETHERSCAN_API,
    }
```

placed into `networks` section

Fix this like that:

```
networks: {
    testnetMatic: {
        url: "https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com/",
        chainId: 80001,
        gasPrice: 20000000000,
        accounts: { mnemonic: mnemonic }
    },
},
etherscan: {
    apiKey: <bscScanApiKey>
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You did import dotenv in the hardhat.config.js but seems like you didn't do it in your deploy.js file.
Importing dotenv in your deploy.js using

```
require("dotenv").config();
```

Should fix your problem. (It did fix mine!)